# Fragmented UDP packets not received by application

Tags: android, linux, debugging, udp, kernel

Very strange behavior...

I have 3 machines:

```
 -----------     ------------     -----------
 | A (x86) |-----| B (x86)  |-----| C (arm) |
 | sender  |     | receiver |     | sender  |
 -----------     ------------     -----------
```

- A and B are Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) machines, kernel 3.2;
- C is an android (ICS) machine, kernel 3.0.8;
- All are connected via RJ45 cables;
- Connections are OK, network is set up correctly;

**Issue is:** when machine C (ARM-android) sends a UDP packet which payload size is over 1472 bytes (maximum payload before packet gets fragmented), server application on machine B is never able to receive it, ... regarding that:

- Source/Dest IP addresses are correct: I can receive all the datagrams I send if I set the payload size less or equal to 1472;
- On machine B (receiver), if I dump network traffic with Wireshark, I can see each fragment, and then re-assembled message => from Wireshark point of view, it's all good!
- Comparing each fragment header as well as re-assembled message with what I can dump when the same message is sent from machine A (which is always received OK), everything seems perfect (only differences are IP addresses, and checksum, since UDP header checksum takes in account IP address fields).
- There is no MTU issue, packets are fragmented as expected.
- There is no router/switch between the machines
- ifconfig shows neither packets drop, nor overflows, nor any other classical error!
- ... this is so weird!!

I've spent some time on Internet, but never found any topic like this one. Each time people has troubles with UDP, either their MTU discovery was not correct, or they did some mishandling in the testing procedure, or they could not dump message on receiver host, ... this is not the case here!!

For sure, I know issue is on sender end (machine C), but maybe is could be easier to enable some logs (at kernel level?) on receiver end to understand why UDP datagram disappears!? Any advice? Are there specific files I could check in /proc/sys/net, or kernel options I should enable?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even though you may be sure please post all the address:port subnet values

Comment: I've finally found the problem.

Comment: I finally found the problem. Adding traces in Linux kernel of machine B, I've been able to understand that datagram got dropped because of bad payload checksum (after being re-assembled). After some time, I figured out the NIC of machine C computed UDP checksum of all the packets regardless they were fragments or not. This resulted in all fragments payload's bytes 7 & 8 to be overwritten by this checksum. I've now fixed the problem in NIC card setup, and all is fine. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: How did you stop the NIC from computing UDP checksum at fragments?

Answer (score 0):

**If your machines are indeed connected as depicted**, i.e. they are not connected to switch/hub, then you must have two NICs on B therefore they will have different addresses so the address you use to send to B from A will not be the same as sending to B from C. i.e.

Could the address you are sending to be wrong? Though that would not explain how smaller datagrams get through - are you sure they are?

Note: Theses addresses would have to be assigned manually as you are not connected to DHCP, furthermore these addresses will need to be in the same subnet as A and C. Are all your addresses (A, BA, BC and C) in the same subnet? What address:port is the socket on B bound to and listening on? Does B continue to receive after receiving a datagram? Please provdie some code..

**OR, even if your machines are connected to a switch/hub,**, is the "Don't fragment" bit set on datagrams sent from C which would explain why larger ones are dropped but not smaller ones.

Comment: I do confirm machine B has two NICS.
I also confirm IP addresses are correct.
Header of messages (including fragment flags) is correct, this is confirmed by Wireshark, and the fact it is able to re-assemble the fragments.
This issue is one of the most weird I've ever seen. Trust me I've spent some time on it, as well as many other persons working with me...
This is the reason why I'm know thinking about adding log information at kernel level.

Comment: No firewall at all on machine B. Neither any specific iptables rule.
Datagrams are always received except when payload size is 1473 and over!!...

Comment: May I should re-phrase my question.
Except if somebody had exactly the same problem and was able to fix it... I actually need some help to know which kind of logs I could enable in kernel -- because issue is in low-level layers --, to help understand what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect machine (C) to the NIC where machine (A) is normally connected to? This is to find out if the problem is the Android machine or the NIC.